Active Scripting Error in Excel Power Query
I have data that I'm extracting from a URL in Power Query, the data is within a table in the URL. The issue I have is when the data contains approx. 3 months of performance (around 22 Thousand rows) it loads perfectly, no issues.
However when I extend the data to 12 months of performance (around 90 Thousand rows). I get the following error message (also shown in screenshot);
The query table couldn't be refreshed:
[DataSource.Error] The Web.Page function requires Active Scripting to be enabled in Internet Explorer options. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506565 for details on how to enable Active Scripting.
Excel Power Query Error Message
I went to the web address (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506565) and it talks about enabling Javascript on Internet Explorer, except IE doesn't exist anymore since June 2022, so I can't download IE on Windows 11.
I double checked Microsoft Edge and Chrome (the 2 browsers installed on my machine) and they show in the settings area that Javascript is enabled. 2nd screenshot shows its enabled in Edge.
Microsoft Edge Javascript Enabled
So I'm confused how to proceed and stop this 'Active Scripting' error from preventing me from importing data into Excel via Power Query?
